# socket.io client can't upgrade from XHR long polling to websocket

Tags: node.js, heroku, websocket, socket.io, long-polling

We have a server which do implement socket.io in NodeJS on Heroku.

We have a bunch of clients (Raspberry pi's) destributed on different networks across our country. They do implement socket.io clients in a NodeJS application.

It do work very well on 17/18 devices. We do have one device which are not able to upgrade the socket.io connection from a long-polling type to an actual websocket.

I cannot find the reason why.

Our server is setup with the following options:
[Server settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WpnHm.png)

This is what the logs on our heroku server tells about the connection with the problematic client:
[Heroku logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6wuV9.png)

As all clients are setup exactly the same way, i do not actually suspect any problems on the raspberries themselves.

Could it be a network problem where this one client is located?
- Behind the router, blocking some port etc?

Hope you have some suggestions to what the problem could be.
You tell if you need anymore information.

Comment: If all Pi's are setup exactly the same (e.g. by cloning the SD card image), it's very likely a network related issue. However, not sure whether it's possible to solve than given the amount of information in your question.

Comment: Thank you @Capricorn for the comment. They are by cloning SD card image. Problem is that even the network should be setup the same way, as our customers use the same internetprovider and router setup.
As i am not any network expert, i am looking for maybe a direction to look. E.g is websockets in need of open port? In my understanding they shold only need standard port 80 or 443 to work.